# Rewrite whole URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have an URL with a subdomain that looks like this:

```
test.my-site.com/
```

Let's say I want to add forums section to it, which works under:

```
test.my-site.com/forums/
```

That works but I want to now rewrite the URL so that every time someone visits the forums section instead of `test.my-site.com/forums` he sees `forums.my-site.com/` in the URL.

I'm trying to do that through the `.htaccess` like that:

```
RewriteRule test.my-site.com/forums/(.*)$ forums.my-site.com/$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```

However, this has absolutely no effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect to forums subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.my-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)$ http://forums.my-site.com/$1 [NC,R=302,NE,L]

# Rewrite from forums subdomain to forums folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forums\.my-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forums/$1 [NE,L]
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working even with your edit. The URL simply does not change.

Comment: Did you configure your server and DNS to work with `forums` subdomain ? That work when you try with `http://forums.my-site.com` ?

Comment: I would guess no. The forums.my-site.com subdomain does not exist at all. If I create it and use the .htaccess above, do I need to input something in that folder at all?

Comment: Depending on the server configuration, normally it is not necessary then to use .htaccess. Because the subdomain is used as an another site. But you can still provide one, like mine, if the user does not see the subdomain is not the same (and you use `/forums/` in the link)

Comment: The correct way to do what you want is what Croises is saying. You need to create a forum subdomain in DNS first and point to it instead of trying to do something fubar.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subdomain forums and use public_html/forums as a directory root for it. Create index.html file in the subdomain directory and use the below html tags:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>you title goes here</title>
</head><frameset rows="100%" scrolling="yes" border="0">
<frame src="test.my-site.com/forums">
</frameset></html>
```

try it and let me know any issue

Comment: I think there's an issue with this. Say I'm browsing to test.my-site.com/forums/topic_name/post_name. If I use your suggestion with the frame, my URL will always say forums.my-site.com and instead I would like it to show forums.my-site.com/topic_name/post_name

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i suggest

```
RewriteRule ^mySite.com/([forum|blog])$ $1.mySite.com/ [QSA,L]
```